# variable in tooltip and the translation

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Would you please help me in this tooltip? It does not work.

```
             <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" 
 matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)"  
 title="{{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}">
```

and here is the  func

```
getTitle(editWidgetsNum) {
return this.translate.instant('Edit_WidgetsNum', {n: 
editWidgetsNum});  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
title="{{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)"}}"
```

or

```
[title]="getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)"
```

Comment: Hi, actually I checked and the translation does dont work! also i need to have mattooltip for black background and it does not work as well. would u please help? like this :                   <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)"  title="{{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}" matTooltipClass="tooltip-black">                                       and i thin it is better to have this var this.editWidgetsNum in ngOnit instead of having new func. like :this.editWidgetsNum= this.translate.instant('Edit_WidgetsNum', {n: this.editWidgetsNum});

Comment: @Nana could you create a sample for it? maybe a stackblitz?

Comment: Thank you for the response.. Now my problem is just using matTooltip for the background, my code does not work, maybe this is because i have not use "title" in when i want to use matTooltip, but i need this "title" , here is my code:  <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)"  title="{{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}">

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tooltip-dynamic?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: My problem is I have "Title" and the title is not static, it is variable, Thisis my ts file: getTitle(editWidgetsNum) {
  return this.translate.instant('Edit_WidgetsNum', {n: editWidgetsNum});
  
 }

Comment: I changed the code in the question , maybe it is easier.

Comment: If you do not use matTooltip, it is working and dynamic, right?
If yes, you should import material module for matTooltip, any console error?

Comment: , without mattooltip it works,  Yes, and No console error, but i tried to import import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip'; but it seems that it is not used, and it does not accept @ngmodul.